# How can I achieve the following grid output in React/JSX?

Tags: django, reactjs

In Django/Bootstrap, I sometimes want a Pinterest-like grid of objects, and I use the following in my templates:

```
<div class="row">
    {% for object in objects %}
        <div className="col-md-3"><!-- Each object code here --></div>
        {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"4" and not forloop.last %}
        </div><div class="row">
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

However, when I try the line `</div><div className="row">` in my JSX template, I get an `Unexpected Token` error because the closing `</div>` tag comes before the opening `<div>` tag (which is what separates rows of objects, in this case each row has 4 objects).

Is there a way to achieve this type of row/column grid while still passing JSX syntax checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, JSX isn't a templating language--it is directly transplited to JavaScript function calls. So, when you're writing JSX, unlike writing templates in Django/Handlebars/etc., you have the full power of JavaScript at your disposal. For that reason, it's usually best to think about shaping your data so you can iterate it easily and create the DOM structure you want. Methods like `map` and `reduce` are your friends here.

For example, say you wanted to render these eight "items" in such a layout:

```
var items = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight"];
```

What you really want to do is render a row for every four objects, and then a div for each object in that row. So let's create a component that splits the data in just such a fashion.

```
var PinterestLayout = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    // Here we'll just use Lo-dash's `chunk` method to split our data
    // into the right sized groups.
    var groups = _.chunk(this.props.items, 4);
    // Now `groups` is an array of arrays that looks like:
    // [ ["one", "two", "three", "four"],
    //   ["five", "six", "seven", "eight"] ]
    //
    // Let's render a row for each group.
    return <div>{groups.map(this.renderRow)}</div>;
  },

  renderRow: function(row) {
    // Now `row` is just an array of four items,
    // which we can render just how you'd expect.
    return <div className="row">{row.map(this.renderItem)}</div>;
  },

  renderItem: function(item) {
    return <div className="col-sm-3">{item}</div>;
  }
});
```

Here's a working example of this on JSBin: https://jsbin.com/hawoya/edit?js,output

Comment: thanks for this! One question - this yields the following warning: `Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of PinterestLayout. See https://fb.me/react-warning-keys for more information.` ...what's the best way to address that using the above render methods?

Comment: @YPCrumble For every component you return from a `map` operation, the component should have a `key={...}` prop with a value that uniquely identifies that item over time. For example, if you're rendering an array of users, you might use `key={user.id}`. In this simple example, there's no unique ID to use, so you could use the index of the iteration, though this is usually not recommended.